# dynamic_cast or redundancy?

Tags: c++, casting, redundancy

In my system low hiearchy objects talk to the high hiearchy object via calling function of the +1 level hiearchy object, which calls a function of the +1 level hiearchy object, etc etc etc, until the function calling stops at the recipent.

There is a Message abstract class, and there are lots of derivated classes, which hold different kinds of datas. 
Like:

- FruitMessage: string, int
- CoordinateMessage: float, float, float

etc etc

And those methods I mentioned before want Message objects so this chaincalling is done through one kind of method instead of creating methods for all of the Message types.

The problem comes, when the recipent receives the Message object.

The recipent wants to know **what's in that message**, so it can **process receives message as the message type requires it**.

*(like it decreases the integer by 1 in FruitMessages, divides the coordinates in CoordinateMessages, etc.)*

Currently I have two ideas, but maybe none of them is correct and I should use a third one. (tell me please)

- The recipent dynamic_casts it while it doesn't the correct type.
- Message has an enum field called MessageType, which is initalized in the derived class' constructor to the correct value, so the recipent just uses a switch-case during the process.

My question is that is it worth the redundancy?

- dynamic_cast is slower than the integer check
- but every time I create a new Message class I have to create a new enum value.

What should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I feel like [virtual functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I would recommend the visitor pattern: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/cpp/2

Comment: Oopsie, edited.
You mean creating a GetType() virtual function, and override it in every subclass so it returns the correct value corresponding the subclass?

Comment: I agree with Dark Falcon.   Used judiciously, the visitor pattern can eliminate the need to check the type of your events entirely.

Comment: I looked at it, but I think that it would just add lots of extra lines (which are redundant too, like the subElements' accept()), instead of having 1 method, with a switch-case of typedef()s

Answer (score 2):

Both ways are OK. Redundancy vs speed is very common problem in Software development.
I would choose dynamic_cast as redundancy is the first step to bugs, but it's really up to you and depends on your performance requirements.
I saw very similar problem while working with Akka, they usually use dynamic_cast (I mean java/scala analogues)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator to check the type of the message. This way, you avoid repeatedly calling `dynamic_cast` until you get the correct type.

```
void process_message(Message const& msg) {
  if (typeid(msg) == typeid(FruitMessage)) {
    auto& fruit_msg = static_cast<FruitMessage const&>(msg);
    …
  }
}
```

Even better, you could use the C++17 [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) container type. An `any` object can be copied around like a non-polymorphic value, and does not require the use of a virtual base class. If you don't have access to a C++17 library implementation, you could use [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) instead.

```
void process_message(std::any const& msg) {
  if (msg.type() == typeid(FruitMessage)) {
    auto fruit_msg = std::any_cast<FruitMessage>(msg);
    …
  }
}
```

As for whether using an `enum` field would be faster than `typeid` or `any`, you'll have to do the benchmarking yourself.

Comment: I like this way. By the way, isn't this a bad practice?

Comment: @Tudvari It's no more bad practice than `dynamic_cast`. Why would you think this is bad practice?

Comment: It's a sign of bad design. (As I heard)

Comment: Downcasting can be a sign of bad design in general. As with most things, there are cases where it is justified.